# Error: ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Tags: node.js, typescript, oracle, node-oracledb

I have this error for a few hours and I can't identify the problem. Error: *ORA-01008: not all variables bound*.

**Controller**

```
async bipagem(req: Request, res: Response) {
        try {
          let credentials = super.openToken(req)
          let { p_fil_filial, p_set_cdgo, p_mini_fab, p_codigo_barra } = req.query
          let info = await this.rep.bipagem(
            p_fil_filial as string,
            p_set_cdgo as string,
            p_mini_fab as string,
            p_codigo_barra as string,
            credentials as string
          )
          res.json(info)
        } catch (error) {
          catchErr(res, error)
        }
      }
    }
```

**Repository**

```
     public async bipagem(
        p_fil_filial: string,
        p_set_cdgo: string,
        p_mini_fab: string,
        p_codigo_barra: string,
        userPool: string
      ) {
        let conn
        try {
          conn = await connection(userPool)
          const ret = await conn.execute(
            `DECLARE
            c_result SYS_REFCURSOR;      
            BEGIN
            -- Call the function
            :result := brio.pck_fab0024.bipagem(p_fil_filial => :p_fil_filial,
            p_set_cdgo => :p_set_cdgo,
            p_mini_fab => :p_mini_fab,
            p_codigo_barra => :p_codigo_barra,
            p_msg => :p_msg);
            DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(c_result);
            END;`,
            {
              p_fil_filial,
              p_set_cdgo,
              p_mini_fab,
              p_codigo_barra,
              p_msg: { type: oracledb.STRING, dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT }
            }
          )
          return { ...(ret.outBinds as object), conteudo: ret.implicitResults[0] }
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('Erro na fab0024: ', e.message)
          return {
            p_fil_filial,
            p_set_cdgo,
            p_codigo_barra,
            p_msg: '',
            conteudo: []
          }
        } finally {
          if (conn && typeof conn !== 'string') conn.close()
        }
      }
    }
```

I tried to include the p_msg parameter and got this return error TS2339: Property 'bipagem' does not exist on type 'unknown'.

Answer (score 1):

Your PL/SQL block has six bind parameters but you are passing only five values.  Hence it is not a surprise that you get an error saying that one of the local variables isn't bound.

I think you have missed the fact that `:result` in the line below is also a bind parameter:

```sql
            :result := brio.pck_fab0024.bipagem(p_fil_filial => :p_fil_filial,
```

I suspect you meant to assign the result to the local variable `c_result` (to which you don't currently assign any value) instead of an extra bind parameter:

```sql
            c_result := brio.pck_fab0024.bipagem(p_fil_filial => :p_fil_filial,
```